# How does a mister form the mist?

Tags: pressure, everyday-life

A mister exploits pressure difference to pull water up from the reservoir and through the outlet (Ref:https://www.explainthatstuff.com/aerosolcans.html )But what converts the water in bulk liquid form to a finely distributed mist. Just the presence of holes wouldn't be much of help for it can only cause it to come out as if from a shower.

So what is the mechanism ?

Comment: Very fine holes in the nozzle cause small droplets (mist,) to form

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fog_machine

Comment: But why does fine holes cause the mist ?